# Antique Faucet replacement

Tags: plumbing, faucet, antique

I’m having serious issues replacing an antique faucet stem on old old claw foot tub.

The hot water nozzle slowly leaks and I can’t find a replacement stem or even a washer that would fit. I emailed Faucet Parts Plus and they replied we have nothing that matches. Does anyone have any suggestions?

The picture is the cold water cartridge which is the one that works. I need a hot water cartridge/stem. (It looks as though it was cobbled together with a different washer to slow the leak) 12 spline.

[image: Cartridge and washer]

Comment: I would recommend taking it to a local plumbing supply house (_not_ a big-box, home improvement store). The odds are good that they'll be able to find you a part that will work. They may have to order it, but they're the ones with experience and calipers to take all the required measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Most hardware stores will be able to find a match. Bring the stem with you. There are usually many replacements in stock. If not the usually have a plumbing parts book or software they can look up the specifications and then special order it for you. It may be helpful to take a picture of the faucet if they want more information.